# For a Custom Object, is there a way to convert/map from a the SFDX file structure to a single .object file?

Tags: salesforce, sfdc-migration-tool

Our development team is currently split between using the ANT migration tool and SFDX to manage deploying our metadata. Currently, our GIT repository and Jenkins pipeline uses the ANT migration tool and associated directory structure to deploy/manage the metadata.

When trying to merge metadata for a CustomObject with our GIT branch, if that code has been retrieved from an authorized org using SFDX, the file structure has the fields, listViews, validationRules, and a single *object-meta.xml file per object.

When viewing the metadata for this same CustomObject but having retrieved it using the ANT migration tool, there is a single CustomObject__c.object file that seems to contains all fields, listViews, and validationRules.

SFDX:

```
CustomObject__c
-->fields
-->listViews
-->validationRules
CustomObject.object-meta.xml
```

ANT Migration Tool:

```
CustomObject.object
```

Is there a way to convert the SFDX directory structure to the ANT Migration Tool .object file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure there is, use the SFDX [cli source commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm)

Comment: Correct answer. Specifically:
sfdx force:source:convert

Comment: I should have specified, sorry. But yes that command is indeed useful for setting up CI/CD with your salesforce projects